# access 2013: how to display calculated values in data table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am developing a *library db system* and building a *front end for the users in ms access*.

I could need some help on how to display calculated values for a record on a form.

let's say we have two tables:

- titles
- instances

there are many titles (e.g. "book title no 1", "book title no 2" ...) and many instances of these titles, i.e. the actual books. every book instance is linked to a title via a title-id.

in the instances table we store additional info like some status on each book (e.g. "ok", "not in best shape"...)

now, if someone searches for a title, I want to display info on all the instances of that title in one table, for example:

> title | no of available instances| "ok" | "not in best shape" ...
>
> "title no 1" | 5 | 3 | 2 ...

This means: the title is from the title table and the other fields are calculations from a join over titles and instances table. what I can't figure out is: how do I display multiple calculated values next to each other in a table on a form?

I managed to show one calculated value (e.g. number of instances of each title) by creating a query calculating the value and then basing the form on this query.

```
SELECT tabTitle.Title, Count(tabInstances.TitleID) AS NoOfInstancesPerTitle
FROM tabTitle INNER JOIN tabInstances ON tabTitle.TitleID = tabInstances.TitleID
GROUP BY tabTitle.Title;
```

But how do I manage to show multiple calculated values?

How can I achieve this? Can someone help me?

Help would be much appreciated!
Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you went down the right path.

I would create a query with the calculated fields and base the form on that:

```
SELECT tabTitle.Title, Count(tabInstances.TitleID) AS NoOfInstancesPerTitle, Sum(iif(tabInstances.Status ="OK",1,0)) as [OK], Sum(iif(tabInstances.Status ="Not in best shapre",1,0)) as [Not In Best Shape] 
FROM tabTitle INNER JOIN tabInstances ON tabTitle.TitleID = tabInstances.TitleID
GROUP BY tabTitle.Title;
```

If your using a lookup table for the status then this query will look slightly different but not much.

Comment: ah, your way of calculating the fields with if clauses might be what I was looking for... thx a lot!